# How to call web services via worklight adapter in a web worker

Tags: multithreading, ibm-mobilefirst, worker, worklight-adapters

I have a requirement to use web worker in my worklight project for a hybrid application. I want to call  web service via worklight adapter in my worker thread. When I am using "  WL.Client
.invokeProcedure " method in my worker.js file , I am getting error (WL is not defined) . Is there any way I can achieve adapter call in my worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

`WL.Client.invokeProcedure` is a client-side API. It is not available in adapters since the SDK that has this method is initialized in the application... not the server. An adapter is a server-side entity. It seems like your web worker is not in the same context as the application, hence the API is not available to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Yes you are right ,web worker is not in the same context as the application . Web workers always run in another global context . So Is there any way I can call adapters from web workers ?